# Check if Logitech K400+ is turned on or off / Logitech K400+ Power Change Event

Tags: usb, powershell, wmi, wireless-keyboard, dongle

I'd like to run a script when I turn my [Logitech K400+](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/products/keyboards/k400-plus-touchpad-keyboard) on or off.

I tried to detect the status of the device using `Get-WmiObject win32_keyboard` and `Get-WmiObject win32_PointingDevice`, however, the device uses the Logitech Unifying Software and the wireless receiver seemingly reports all devices (or pseudo devices?) back as `Status: OK` no matter if they are turned on or off.

I also tried `Get-PnpDevice` but seemingly no changes either. Are there any other ways to check if the device is turned on or off?

I know the Logitech Unifying Software has a function to `Save System Report...`, this report includes the device status (`Wireless Status : 0x1` or `Wireless Status : 0x0`), so there's probably a way to retrieve this information, but I've no idea how.